# JQuery Sortable drags divs, but doesnt sort after releasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I am trying to make the items within the div #h_red_printable (which are dynamically added when the page loads, and have a class "chart_container") sortable, but what happens is I can drag them around, but when I release the click, the div comes back where it was before. Any suggestions?

Dummy HTML:

```
   *<div id="printable_charts" style="display:none;height:auto;">

            <div id="printable_hw">
               <img class="banner-img" src="/static/app/ihi/hardware.png" />
              <div id="h_red_printable" class="cat_column">
                  <div class="chart_container"> 
                      <div class=".add_stuff" style="position:absolute;">Stuff here</div>
</div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>*
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $( "#h_red_printable" ).sortable();
    $( "#h_red_printable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

And yes, I have included these two scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Could you make a snippet in jsfiddle?

Comment: Do you have any special css? Can you show use what your css classes look like?

Comment: @keiv.fly unfortunately I can't because there are a lot of things inside the div, of which some are loaded through a third party that needs auth.. The "chart_container" div has another div inside that has position:relative, and that div has a lot of elements positioned absolute. Edited the code* .The chart_container has no positioning set yet.

Comment: Also, when are the elements added to the list of sortable items? If this happens after you call sortable(), you will need to call `$('#h_red_printable').sortable('refresh')`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp They get added after the page loads. So, I call ..sortable('refresh') after some event fired, or I just add the snipped after the ..sortable() call?

Comment: $('#h_red_printable').sortable('refresh') has to be called right after elements have been added to the list of items. I don't know how these are added... Is an event triggered when this happens, or is there a callback function?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp I have the divs in one place when the page loads. On a button click, they get added(appended) to the #h_red_printable div. Let me try and call the ('refresh') method after they get appended. Good catch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the inner div (Stuff here) absolute positioned.

```
 <div class="chart_container">Stuff here</div>
```

Comment: Have you added "jquery-ui.css" ?

Comment: Yes, I have.. tried repositioning, but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Since elements are added on a button click, and thus after $("#h_red_printable" ).sortable(); is called, add an event handler to that button click event like this, in order to refresh the list of sortable elements:

```
$('#theButton').click(function (e) {
   $('#h_red_printable').sortable('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Of course, you have to adjust the selector in the code above. Also, if there is already a click handler you have access to, you can add your code in there, which might be safer to make sure that the refresh is executed after the elements are added to the DOM.